# Twitter integration ( callback URL) enable callback locking

Tags: android, ios, twitter-oauth

In twitter Application management , when you create an application, now I am not able to find enable callback locking option which was shown earlier when we used to add callback url . Is this permanently removed. So now apps can overwrite the callback url?.What about existing applications.